# SUMIFS Function, only summing the first true conditions and omitting the remaining conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I'm are trying to calculate the number of visits to a website by country, but we do not want to include all the countries on the list, only specific ones.
The formula I'm using works, however, it only sums the first country on the list that matches the true condition and not the remaining countries on the list.

We have tried the following:

[Screenshot from Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuwP.png)

Using the following formula

=SUMIFS(C6:C17,B6:B17,A2:A3,A6:A17,E3)

and it isn't summing the visits for Spain and Italy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SUMIFS when you have more than one optional condition (Spain OR Italy, in this case) you can sum two SUMIFS, one for each of the conditions. In this case, when in your formula you say E2:E3 it's only grabbing the first value:

```
=SUMIFS(C6:C17,B6:B17,A2,A6:A17,E3)  +  SUMIFS(C6:C17,B6:B17,A3,A6:A17,E3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=sum(ifna(filter(C6:C17,xmatch(B6:B17,A2:A3),A6:A17=E3)))
```